# Creating a network which allows communication between containers but no internet access

Tags: docker, testcontainers

How can I create a docker network using `testcontainers` which:

- allows for all containers in the network to communicate with each
- allows for containers to map ports to the host
- but does not allow containers to have access to the internet

I have tried to do this using an `internal` network:

```java
private Network generateInternalNetwork() {
     // Consumer which operates on the final CreateNetworkCmd which will be run to
     // make sure the 'internal' flag is set.
     Consumer<CreateNetworkCmd> cmdModifier = (createNetworkCmd) -> {
         createNetworkCmd.withInternal(true);
     };

     return Network.builder()
             .createNetworkCmdModifier(cmdModifier)
             .build();
}
```

However, when I run this I cannot have my port mapped. An exception is thrown:

`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Requested port (8024) is not mapped`

If I run it without `withInternal(true)` it works fine but of course the containers have internet access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending a few days trying different things I have come up with a hack of a solution that kind-of works:

```java
    /**
     * Set an invalid DNS for the given container.
     * This is done as a workaround so that the container cannot access
     * the internet.
     */
    void setInvalidDns() {
        GenericContainer<?> container = getContainer();
        Consumer<CreateContainerCmd> modifier = (cmd) -> {
                // Amend the config with the garbage DNS.
                String invalidDns = "255.255.255.255";
                HostConfig hostConfig = cmd.getHostConfig();
                hostConfig.withDns(invalidDns);
                cmd.withHostConfig(hostConfig);
        };

        container.withCreateContainerCmdModifier(modifier);
    }
```

This sets the container's DNS to an invalid IP and then when you try to make a HTTP request in the container it will throw a `java.net.ConnectException`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can get what you want by (a) creating normal networks, and then (b) adding a `DROP` rule to your `DOCKER-USER` firewall chain:

```
iptables -I DOCKER-USER -j DROP
```

In my quick experiment just now, this let me map ports from containers, but prevented the containers from accessing the internet (because this chain is called from the `FORWARD` chain, to it prevents containers from forwarding traffic through the host to the outide internet).

Comment: i'm curious though if there's a way to do this at the docker layer and not involve the OS.

Comment: like @Joe says - do you know how I can do this at the docker level (using testcontainers if possible).