# How to run an iptables command for docker for windows when using WSL2

Tags: docker, docker-desktop, wsl-2

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 on WSL 2 along with docker desktop (2.3.0.5) for Windows.

Docker desktop has been setup so that I can access the docker daemon from my Ubuntu shell.

I would like to run the command (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64094354/5108875) for motivation for running the command):

```sh
sudo iptables -I DOCKER-USER -j DROP
```

but when I do I get the error:
`iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.`

According to the [docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/network/iptables/): "Docker installs two custom iptables chains named DOCKER-USER and DOCKER, and it ensures that incoming packets are always checked by these two chains first."

How can I apply this iptable rule to the docker desktop installation on windows?

Answer (score 1):

The documentation specifies that it's a feature for a Linux environment.

> On Linux, Docker manipulates iptables rules to provide network isolation.

Have you tried using iptables within WSL2 itself? If you're using Docker desktop with the WSL2 Ubuntu integration, it might work.

Comment: That command is within wsl2  becuase winwods does not know about sudo